# Random Crashes When Running 3D Software of Any Kind

Tags: windows-10, crash, gpu, gaming, nvidia-geforce

I'm having issues with games randomly crashing without any errors, but sometimes with a crash reporter for the software appearing. It's not a new computer by any means, but also software that used to run perfectly fine started crashing.

GTX970, i5-3570K, 16 GB RAM, Windows 10

Could someone please help me with advice on what I should do to try and identify the cause?

*I've monitored the GPU temperature, and that doesn't seem to be the problem. It's steady just above 60 degrees Celsius.*

I started considering the PSU since I purchased a computer fully assembled and I did replace my GPU a while back *(what do I know? Maybe they put in a PSU that just had enough power to supply their build? But as I'm not that smart, I did no investigations. I just crammed stuff in there)*. And I've also installed an extra SSD, but I'm pretty sure the crashes didn't start until much later. What I do remember, which might just be a coincidence but I can't really let it go. I'm pretty sure the first time it crashed was when I did a HUD modification in Elite Dangerous *(just editing a text file to change the color)* which didn't work, and then the game crashed shortly after starting it up. I backed up my changes and then the game *(Elite Dangerous)* started crashing randomly, and more frequently over time. It never happened with the game before. It then also started in other games that always ran without problems previously. Like WoW and GTA V. All heavy 3D games are now crashing. I've recently tried Farcry 5 which will never run more than 5 minutes.

It also happens on occasion when I'm modelling in Blender. Most games that are light or not 3D at all, doesn't seem to have the problem.

Drivers and such are up to date. I also took out the GPU and ensured there isn't any collection of dust anywhere.

*Anyway, long rant with little useful information, and I don't expect anyone to find a solution for me. But any advice on what diagnostic software to use (and what to look for when using them),  logs to review, or any other "standard" solutions of any kind is much welcome.*

Comment: I would suggest: 1. create C:\dumps\, 2. Download procdump from Sysinternals to the directory.  In an admin Prompt, run `procdump -ma -i C:\dumps` Next time the game crashes do you get a dump file in C:\dumps\  If so can you link it here?

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, but no dump file was created. I used procdump64 and the tmp-folder. But the rest I did exactly like you said. Not sure if my alterations made it not work.

Comment: I now also tried the non-64 version just to be sure. But no change.

Comment: I spoke to a friend of mine that claims he had the same issue once, and that it then was a PSU issue.

Comment: In that case the application isn't crashing but likley terminating due to a handled condition. 2 Options: 1. Create a dump using procdump on terminate. You can remove procdump from the registry, using `procdump -u`.  To capture a dump on terminate: If you can launch the process and it runs for a while you can run: `procdump -t notepad.exe C:\dumps`. Change notepad.exe to the process that is crashing.  The other option is to run Process Monitor (Sysinternals), when the process exits, check the details of the process exit for the exit code. Put this into `certutil -error x`. x is the exit code.

Comment: Using procdump rendered "Error debugging process - Access Denied" whereupon the process immediately crash.

I will get on trying the other option

Comment: Did you run the command from a admin command prompt?

Comment: I would run prime95 for 10 minutes and see what happens. If that's fine then gpu/driver/psu is where I'd focus on next.

Comment: Sorry for not replying. I've been pre-occupied and not been able to deal with this. I will get back at it soon. I just wanted to let you know that I really appreciate your help!

Comment: I was running it from an admin command prompt indeed